# Ranking by Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, ranking

I have the following data table called "animal" and I want to rank and group by clone version based on animal.

```
Animal Clone_Version
dog    0
dog    0
dog    1
dog    2
dog    2
```

I have tried using the following code but it lacks the grouping aspect I am looking for. As this is what it returns.

```
select 
x.animal
, x.clone_version
, row_number() over(partition by x.clone_version order by animal desc) 
from animal x
```

This is what the above code returns.

```
Animal  Clone_Version  RankGroup
dog      0              2
dog      0              1
dog      1              1
dog      2              2
dog      2              1
```

I want to rank these by grouping, so the output would be the following.

```
Animal  Clone_Version  RankGroup
dog      0              3
dog      0              3
dog      1              2
dog      2              1
dog      2              1
```

Do I need to utilize a select statement in the from clause or is there some way to reconfigure the `row_number() over(partition by....order by...)` to allow grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `DENSE_RANK`:

```
select 
x.animal
, x.clone_version
, dense_rank()
  over(partition by x.animal        -- for each animal
       order by clone_version desc) -- based on descending version
from animal x
```

But if your clone version is always increasing it's the same as:

```
select 
x.animal
, x.clone_version
, MAX(clone_version)
  over(partition by x.animal) - clone_version + 1
from animal x
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Worked like a charm.  If you get a chance, could you explain how the "- clone_version + 1" part works? I see that it works but I am struggling as to why it works.

Comment: @AlmostThere: The `MAX` returns the highes `clone_version` for each `animal`. Then you subtract the current `clone_version` and add one to start with `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: I forgot a major data element and have rephrased my OP.

Comment: Never mind, It is a bad idea to rephrase the question, sorry for the inconvenience and I could not delete my previous comment.